# Bootstrap - сделать колонку на всю ширину если вторая пустая

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Есть приметно такой шаблон:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-6">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Контент вставляется в js. Собственно вопрос, есть ли вариант сделать первую колонку на всю ширину, если вторая пустая, не меняя классы в js, ну или хотя бы на уровне - скрыть вторую колонку. Любые варианты.

Comment: при каком условии вторая колонка пустая?

Comment: ну есть условие в js что нет контента, фактически шаблон приходит в состояние которое я отобразил в примере

Comment: если условие в js , тогда можно менять класс на `col-sm-12`, либо `width:100%` для первого блока, второму либо  `display:none` , либо удалять

Comment: суть в том что хотелось бы избежать этого, что бы далее не было казусов что меняешь шаблон и не ясно что происходит, так как манипуляция в js с классами, было бы более прозрачно если к примеру добавить класс для скрытия колонок и отобразить  одну в js если есть контент (собственно такая логика везде на странице, по этому путаницы не возникнет), но у нее класс col-sm-6, что не дает ей встать на всю ширину, от сюда и весь вопрос, есть ли иной путь

Comment: Вашу логику, я описал выше. Если вы меняете шаблон, добавляйте и классы такие же, адаптируйте код js под новую разметку. Лекарства от всех бед - нет. Могу в ответе базово описать, как можно все это реализовать, при текущем условии.

Comment: я не меняю шаблон, я добавляю контент. Я не прошу волшебную пилюлю, а спрашиваю, возможно кто то видеть иной вариант кроме того что вижу я. Смысла писать ответ нет, как заменить класс я в курсе.

Comment: _что меняешь шаблон и не ясно что происходит_ / _я не меняю шаблон, я добавляю контент_ . Определитесь уже, пожалуйста, либо четче выражайте то, что хотите донести до людей.

Comment: Возможно и я не так выражаюсь, но может и вы не ловите суть, _меняешь шаблон и не ясно что происходит_ - имелось ввиду менять шаблон в html файле а не в js, в будущем, другим разработчиком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать такое, используя flexbox.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
</div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex; /* I now declare this as a flex-container */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* This is the Chrome notation */

  min-height: 150px;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;

  /* Just some color and shape */
  background: #bbb;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 2px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/usedtobeme/pen/jDAgb

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант (аналогично можно сделать и на `flex`)

```css
.row-table{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;  
}

.row-table [class*=col-]{  
  background: #ccc;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.row-table [class*=col-]:nth-of-type(2){   
  background: #777;
}
.row-table [class*=col-]:empty{
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='row row-table'>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">content</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='row row-table'>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='row row-table'>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за вариант, решил на основе flex сделать.